# will ms sql server reuse deleted primary keys in auto increment mode?

Tags: sql-server, limit, sqldatatypes

Suppose i have 100 rows in my table, my primary key is integer which is auto incrementing by 1 from 1. I consolidate my data and clear the table once row id reaches 100, will SQL server reuse the deleted primary keys ?

since primary key is incrementing by 1, if the answer of above question is no, what will happen to the next insert, once the primary key reached the biggest possible number an 'Int' can hold  ?

Comment: You can find out realllllly easy if you were to take 5 minutes and test this. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: better to ask than adding 2,147,483,647 rows in my table, to check whether the IDs will start from 1 after entering 200 core rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MSSQL will not re-use the primary keys that have been deleted using `DELETE` (I'm assuming you are talking about the `identity` incrementation.)  If you `TRUNCATE` the table it will reset the seed and reuse them.

If you go over the max for `INT` it will indeed just fail to make the next row.  You can convert your `INT` column to `BIGINT` to avoid that.

`BIGINT` has a max of: `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`  and `INT` has a cap of `2,147,483,647` but note.. you can also use those negative values too!

You can read about those caps here: https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 3):

No, SQL Server won't reuse IDs. If you have 100 records with IDs 1 throught 100 and delete them all, next inserted row will have ID = 101.

But if you want to start from 1 after deleting, you can use this command:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('TableName', RESEED, 0)
```

It will reseed your identity and make it start from 1 all over again.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by

> I...clear the table once row id reaches 100

If you're issuing a `DELETE` statement, then no, the identity column will issue `101` on the next insert.

If you're issuing a `TRUNCATE TABLE` statement, then yes, the table will reseed to `1` (or whatever your seed value is) on the next insert.